# How to install Ubuntu on SSD?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, ssd, grubrescue

I want to install just one OS (Ubuntu) on SSD. Actually I haven't got any other OS in HDD (like Windows).
I have installed Ubuntu on SSD, but I always get errors like:

1. You need to load kernel
2. Can't read section from hd0
   and etc.

Sometimes after booting, it goes to GRUB shell.

My partition on SSD was:

```
/boot  ->   primary, ex4
/      ->   primary, ex4
```

How should I fix it?

**UPDATE**
It works in HDD fine, but in SSD, when I have installed it, it reboots correctly and I can go to my ubuntu and work with it, but when I shut down my laptop(Lenovo), It can't load my ubuntu

Comment: what version are you installing? Are you doing partitioning manually? Or automatic? We'll go from there.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. I have used 'something else' for partitioning. And I also used all of other, but I got same result

Comment: If UEFI system and UEFI install you need an ESP - efi system partition formatted FAT32 300 to 600MB. Most desktops do not need /boot partition, but servers and maybe LVM might. Some like /home or data partitions, so system & data are separate to make reinstall and backup easier.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: It works in HDD fine, but in SSD, when I have installed it, it reboots correctly and I can go to my ubuntu and work with it, but when I shut down my laptop(Lenovo), It can't load my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

what ssd brand are you using? I recently bought a kingston ssd and learned that not all ssd work well out of the box with gnu/linux as evidenced with threads like this.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/aodqqw/psa_dont_buy_ssds_from_the_kingston_a400_line/

what you could try looking for is googling "ssd brand + linux" to see if there are any problems.

At least in my case, ssd needed a firmware update, bad news was that it can only be done using a Windows OS.

I hope it's useful, any info you can add about the hardware you're running could be helpful to help solve your Ubuntu install.

Comment: Oooops!! 
It's ADATA, SU650

Comment: If I install windows and also install ubuntu as a dual boot, it can be handle?

Comment: yeah you can dual boot on SSDs without problems, they behave exactly like HDDs you are used to.